# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContentContainer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, browser

Recently I started noticing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContentContainer' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (content.js:135)
```

I noticed this in my Angular project, but I also noticed that some of the "big" websites also have this error when I open the console. What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Maybe it's because of a chrome extension? Try running it in safe mode and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: You are right, in incognito mode there is no error. Is there some way to prevent this error in code so it will not display to users that are not using incognito mode?

Comment: No, you cannot decide which extensions will run on the browser, actually you don't have anything to do if the user installs broken extensions

Comment: Same here! The problematic extension is "Loom".

Comment: You are right. I disabled the Loom and the error is gone. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As we diagnosed in the comments, it turns out to be a broken chrome extension that throws the error.

Extension name: `Loom`

Therefore the only solution to fix this is to disable the extension (or either check for the extension updates and maybe it got fixed on the next versions)

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, "Loom" is the extension you are looking for.

Comment: uninstalled "Loom" and worked for me as well!

Comment: Thanks! Just disabled the extension and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Instead of disable you can make it run only when click on loom icon. This way also solved the issue.

Comment: I removed loom extension from my chrome and it works fine thanks bro : )